# Meaning of dysphoria

Tags: meaning, word-usage, nouns, connotation

Is the word dysphoria now colloquially only attributed to gender dysphoria?

I recently used the word to describe general anxiety and people assumed I was talking about gender dysphoria.

Can the word be used when talking about general anxiety or distress?

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster defines *dysphoria* as (emphasis mine):

> :  a **generalized** state of feeling unwell or unhappy — opposed to
> *euphoria*

Other people may have only ever heard *dysphoria* used in the context of gender, hence their narrow understanding of it.

If you look up *dysphoria* in a corpus (such as [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)), many of its usages are in the context of gender, but a fair number are not.

Comment: Right. Just wondering if the connotation has changed in our day and age. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I guess seasickness is a good example of *dysphoria*.